# Even length part of exterior algebra as a commutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$.
Define $\bigwedge^{\text{even}}(V) = \bigoplus_{k = 0}^{\lfloor \frac{\dim V}{2} \rfloor} \bigwedge^{2k}(V).$
This is a (finitely generated) commutative subalgebra of the [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) $\bigwedge(V).$

I'm looking for a reference describing $\bigwedge^{\text{even}}(V)$ as
a quotient of a polynomial algebra.

Comment: Do you want a reference specifically, or would a description fit your needs ?

Comment: I would prefer a reference, but I'll take a description if the reference isn't available. :)

Comment: are you sure you want it from a polynomial algebra? as I would suggest you should look at it as a subobject of the symmetric algebra over the vectorspace, respectively, I would actually think of it as the intersection of the exterior algebra and the symmetric algebra.

Comment: @Enkidu Yes, I'm interested in the ''generators and relations'' description. Part about generators isn't hard (see A. Hubery's answer), but I want to find out about relations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write it as a quotient of the symmetric algebra on the vector space $\bigwedge^2V$, so the image of the canonical map
$$ \phi\colon S^\bullet(\textstyle{\bigwedge^2}V) \to \textstyle{\bigwedge^\bullet}(V). $$

Edit: The relations.

We can write the generators of $S^\bullet(\bigwedge^2V)$ as $x_{ij}$ for $1\leq i<j\leq\dim V$. Then the kernel $I$ of $\phi$ clearly contains the elements
$$ x_{ij}x_{kl} = \begin{cases}
0 &\textrm{if }\{i,j\}\cap\{k,l\}\neq\emptyset\\
\pm x_{ab}x_{cd} &\textrm{if }\{i,j\}\cup\{k,l\}=\{a,b,c,d\}
\textrm{ with }a<b<c<d
\end{cases} $$
(where the signs are taken appropriately).

To see that these are all relations, note that the quotient $S^\bullet(\bigwedge^2V)/I$ is spanned as a vector space by products $x_{a,b}x_{c,d}\cdots x_{e,f}$ with $a<b<c<d<\cdots<e<f$. On the other hand, the images of these elements form a basis for $\bigwedge^{2\bullet}V$.

Comment: Do you know what is the kernel of this map?

Comment: To explain better: I'm interested in ''generators and relations'' description of this algebra. As you notice, if we choose a basis for $V$, let's say $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, we can write generators as $x_{ij} := x_i \wedge x_j, 1 \leq i < j \leq n$. We have relations such as $x_{ij}^2 = 0, x_{ij}x_{kl} = x_{ik}x_{lj}...$ I'm wondering if this is a complete system of relations (in other words, if these elements generate the kernel of your map).